"On a best-effort basis" or "on the best-effort basis"
I have always written "on a best-effort basis", but I have recently seen a usage of "on the best-effort basis".
I am wondering if using the definite article "the" in this phrase is correct.
If both are correct, which variant is the most popular?
A bit more context: this was used in programming when discussing the destruction of operating system processes that hang forever. Since the operation might not always succeed depending on the system, we are trying to stop these processes "on a best-effort basis".

on a best efforts basis (plural) https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/best-efforts/#:~:text=The%20best%20efforts%20clause%20in,and%20abide%20by%20contractual%20obligations.&text=A%20party%20involved%20in%20a,to%20the%20highest%20degree%20attainable.

In my experience it's on the basis of [something] but on a [something] basis.

Thanks for your comments! So indefinite article it is. And indeed it seems the plural is more appropriate (yet another issue with my phrase apparently :D)

What @TimR said. Hyphenation is optional, but as this usage chart shows, we nearly always pluralize best efforts in this context.
